# Tons of issue with protoc

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm trying to make `protoc` output the generated files to a folder inside the folder where all my `.proto` files are. First of all, I hope we can agree that this commands are confusing and isn't very intuitive. I stumbled upon this [documentation](https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/go-generated/) which seems to explain everything, but things doesn't work. So my `protobuf` files are inside a folder called proto. I have a few `protobuf` files that imports another `protobuf` file. I import them like this:

```
package proto;

option go_package = "github.com/me/golang-grpc-server/proto";

import "proto/another_proto.proto";

message Proto1 {
    ...
    ...
    repeated proto.AnotherProto another_proto = 6;
}
```

That should work right? Well, `protoc` doesn't know what to do with it. If I run this command.

```
protoc --proto_path=proto --go_out=out --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=out --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative proto1.proto another_proto.proto
```

`protoc` would give me these errors:

```
proto/another_proto.proto: File not found.
proto1.proto:7:1: Import "proto/another_proto.proto" was not found or had errors.
proto1.proto:16:14: "proto.AnotherProto" is not defined.
proto1.proto:40:14: "AnotherProto" is not defined.
```

If I then put `another_proto.proto` in front of `proto1.proto`, I get these errors:

```
proto/another_proto.proto: File not found.
proto1.proto:7:1: Import "proto/another_proto.proto" was not found or had errors.
proto1.proto:16:14: "proto.AnotherProto" seems to be defined in "another_proto.proto", which is not imported by "proto1.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
proto1.proto:40:14: "proto.AnotherProto" seems to be defined in "another_proto.proto", which is not imported by "proto1.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

Then if I remove `--proto_path=proto` and add `proto\` infront of every `protobuf`, I won't get those errors, but the generated files would be placed inside `out\proto` which is very confusing because I thought `--go_opt=paths=source_relative` tells `protoc` to place the outputs inside where the `protobuf`s are placed, as stated [here](https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/go-generated/#invocation) which in my case is the folder `proto`.

> If the paths=source_relative flag is specified, the output file is
> placed in the same relative directory as the input file. For example,
> an input file protos/buzz.proto results in an output file at
> protos/buzz.pb.go.

I tried using `--go_out=proto/out`, but annoyingly it placed the generated files inside `proto/out/proto`. I'm guessing it's because of the `proto/` infront of the `protobuf`s, because of the previously mentioned errors, I might have to stick to `out/proto` for now as it's the currently most sensible path right now.

UPDATE:

I'm not quite sure if I understand @Daz correctly, but here's what my interpretation of your instructions.

So I made this changes to `Proto1`:

```
package src;

option go_package = "github.com/me/golang-grpc-server/proto/src";

import "src/another_proto.proto";

message Proto1 {
    ...
    ...
    repeated src.AnotherProto another_proto = 6;
}
```

I moved all the other protobufs inside a folder under `proto` and of course changed the `go_package` of each one to have `/src` at the end and changed the import parts as well to reflect the change. Then I modified my `protoc` command to this:

```
protoc --proto_path=proto/src --go_out=./out --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=./out --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative proto/src/*.proto
```

That `*` was awesome. Same thing here, modified it to reflect the changes made to the folder structure. Unfortunately, the changes doesn't work, starting from the `protobuf`s themselves. `import` doesn't seem to acknowledge the change in `go_package` or the `package`. If I use "src/another_proto.proto" as the import path, the linter would say that the path was "not found or has errors". Then when I use "proto/src/another_proto.proto", the errors would be gone, but when I run `protoc`, it would throw the previous "not found ..." errors.

UPDATE:

Man, this is some pretty infuriating situation which might be caused by a bug or just missing functionality on `protoc go`. So I was trying to push the command to place the stubs to a more logical I guess directory and so I modified the `protoc` command to have a longer `--proto_path` because I thought doing that could shave folders to the final output path. Each time I added a folder to the `--proto_path`, I modified the `protobuf`'s `go_package` and `import` as well because errors about "not found" `protobuf` would appear. On my current command, the `protobufs` would look like this:

```
package src;

option go_package = "github.com/me/golang-grpc-server/proto/src";

import "another_proto.proto";

message Proto1 {
    ...
    ...
    repeated AnotherProto another_proto = 6;
}
```

which looks quite pretty. But, linter doesn't like it. I guess because of the fact, as @Daz mentioned, that `protobuf` doesn't really use `Golangs` package system, the linter doesn't know how to reference the `import`. Now, I have a project that I think should build, but has 2 files with errors. Here's my current command, this places the stubs to another folder in the same level as the `proto` folder:

```
protoc --proto_path=proto/src --go_out=out --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=out --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative proto/src/*.proto
```

Comment: Yes, it's confusing but it is "predictable" too. Once you grok it, it will work consistently. I'll write an answer to try to help

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's challenging.

The good news: once you understand the process, it will work consistently. I use the following approach with Golang, Rust and Python on Linux and it has worked well for me.

###### 1. Protobuf sources, packages and folders

Protobuf source files define a package (!) hierachy.

I'll use Google's [Well-known Types (WKT)](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/) by way of example. These files are in a protobuf (!) package `google.protobuf`. When you install `protoc`, generally these files are installed too in a folder called `include` and each WKT e.g. [`Timestamp.proto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto) exists in a file-system folder derived from the `package` name (!):

```
{SOME-FOLDER}/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.pro
```

So Protobuf package paths map to file system folder paths **but** they must be anchored on some file-system folder (e.g. `include` in this case). This root folder `{SOME-FOLDER}/include` is the `proto_path` value in `protoc`. And package references from other proto sources that wish to import protos under this root folder are relative to this `proto_path` value as the root e.g. `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";` (no `include` but the folder path from this root must be reflected).

###### 2. Compiled protos aka "stubs", packages and folders

Protobuf supports compilation to multiple languages and each has its unique quirks. Since you asked about Golang, I'll provide the Golang answer.

Protobuf and Golang share similarities in the package naming but it's important to remember that -- in many cases -- the protobuf source (!) `package` does not necessarily map to the language's packages.

For Golang, you **must** tell protoc the Golang packages that you want to use:

```golang
option go_package="example.com/path/to/package";
```

The WKT `Timestamp` is implemented by Google [`Timestamppb`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb) in `google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestampb` package (entirely unrelated to `google.protobuf`

###### So...

In your example, I think you should remove on the `proto` references in your protobuf sources since this folder represents your project hierarchy **not** the protobuf `package` hierarchy.

Either as you have (!) the parent folder (!) of the file system folder `proto` becomes your `proto_path` because your package hierarchy starts at `proto` (or you have `proto/proto` which would be confusing):

```protobuf
package proto;

import "proto/another_proto.proto";
```

Or, as I recommend (!) you choose either a different package `foo` (or remove the package), continue to anchor `proto_path` on `${SOME_FOLDER}/proto` and correct the import mechanism:

```
proto
└── foo
    ├── another_proto.proto
    └── some.proto
```

And `some.proto`:

```protobuf
package foo;

// Golang package is {GO-MODULE}/{GO-PACKAGE}
// Generally GO-PACKAGE={PROTO_PATH}/{PACKAGE} but it need not be
// You can change "${MODULE}/some/random/bar" here without problem
option go_package="github.com/me/golang-grpc-server/proto/foo";

// `another_proto.proto` is in the same `package` and thus same folder
import "foo/another_proto.proto";

// Proto1 is a message that ...
message Proto1 {
    ...
    ...
    // Type references must include the full `package` path e.g. `foo`
    repeated foo.AnotherProto another_proto = 6;
}
```

Using `--go_opt=paths=source_relative` is common but my preference (mostly because it makes sense to me) is the following:

```bash
# Golang Module name
# Protobuf sources will be `option go_package="${MODULE}/proto/foo";`
MODULE="github.com/me/golang-grpc-server"

go mod init ${MODULE}

# proto_path roots the source on "proto"
# Individual protos reflect the package in the folder under "proto"
# Using "foo" as the `package` name requires proto/foo/...
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/proto
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
${PWD}/proto/foo/some.proto \
${PWD}/proto/foo/another_proto.proto
```

Because everything is under `${PWD}/proto/foo`, you can just `${PWD}/proto/foo/*.proto` too.

Yields:

```
.
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── proto
    └── foo
        ├── another_proto.pb.go
        ├── another_proto.proto
        ├── some.pb.go
        └── some.proto
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of info for a small wanted change. Well, failed again by some incomprehensive tutorial. Will try this out later. Can you give some stuff I could read related to that? Is the official documentation good enough? It doesn't seem to have good examples

Comment: [protobuf.dev](https://protobuf.dev) is improved. The [examples](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/main/examples) are helpful too but neither provides much by way of example of a source hierarchy of packages unfortunately. Google uses Protobuf (and gRPC) extensively and so, often you can browse Google's SDKs' sources to see how Google does it, e.g. [go-genproto](https://github.com/googleapis/go-genproto).

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation, and the information is current!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to @DazWilkin's initial answer, I finally found the command to do what I wanted to do. Here it is:

```
protoc --proto_path=proto/src --go_out=./proto/out --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=./proto/out --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative proto/src/*.proto
```

I think the most important bit here is the `--proto_path`. Making it have the exact folder where my `protobuf`s are, made me able to use whatever `--go_out` that I wanted. So `protoc` won't need to add the additional/leading folder that is missing in the `--proto_path` if it isn't the exact one.

Then on your `protobuf`s, you'll have to do this:

```
package src;

option go_package = "github.com/me/golang-grpc-server/proto/src";

import "another_proto.proto";

message Proto1 {
    ...
    ...
    repeated AnotherProto another_proto = 6;
}
```

As mentioned on my last update, linter doesn't seem to like this because it doesn't know how to handle `protobuf` in this kind of setup probably.